# mostrar los datos de una consulta multiple SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

tengo este codigo que va perfecto y todo, pero mi pregunta es, como haria para ?¿mostrar los datos?
osea cuando hago una consulta simple solo me basta con escribir:

```
**while($datosx = mysqli_fetch_array($consulta)){
 echo $datosx["fila de la tabla"]; }**
```

pero ahora mi codigo es el siguiente:

```
$consulta= "SELECT publicaciones.usuario, amigos.id_1, amigos.id_2, 
             publicaciones.id
             FROM publicaciones, amigos 
             WHERE publicaciones.usuario = 
             amigos.id_1 and amigos.id_2 = '$id' ";
             $resultado_consulta = mysqli_query($conexion,$consulta);
```

osea relacione dos tablas para poder filtrar solo elementos que quiero, pero mi pregunta es como puedo mostrar los datos que saque??

Comment: te refieres a mostrarlos en una tabla?

Comment: exactamente eso busco!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En el select has de ponerle un alias a cada campo, y lo llamas exactamente igual. Ejemplo:

```
$consulta= "SELECT publicaciones.usuario AS user, amigos.id_1 AS id_1, amigos.id_2 AS id_2, 
             publicaciones.id AS id
             FROM publicaciones, amigos 
             WHERE publicaciones.usuario = 
             amigos.id_1 and amigos.id_2 = '$id' ";
             $resultado_consulta = mysqli_query($conexion,$consulta);
```

y lo llamas con:

`echo $datosx["user"];
 echo $datosx["id_1"];
 echo $datosx["id_2"];
 echo $datosx["id"];`

Comment: Recuerda que es peligroso pasar el "$id" directamente como variable. Es propenso a ataques de inyección sql.

Comment: Gracias!! Me funciono perfectamente, tomaré en cuenta lo de la variable, me sacaste del apuro enserio!

Comment: me alegro te haya servido :). Por otro lado, lo que dice @mrc_es es cierto, nunca es recomendable enviar IDs de las tablas, hay muchas maneras de referenciar ese registro sin mostrar el ID al usuario

Comment: No es por el id, es por la forma de sustituir la variable. Es decir, alguien del lado del cliente podría enviar un id (con curl) de la forma `'; DROP DATABASES; --` y eso se ejecutaría en el servidor de la forma `SELECT etc FROM etc where etc AND amigo.id_2 = ''; DROP DATABASES; -- `
Pueden ver más en: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Comment: O puede poner el famoso `' OR 1 = 1 ; -- ` el en id y te devolvería todos los datos en el ESLECT sin importar las condiciones del `WHERE`, puesto que el `OR 1=1` inyectado siempre será verdadero.

Answer (score 0):

Sólo como complemento a lo que respondio @guillem, mi punto principal es la seguridad de esa consulta. Creo que sería mejor arreglarla de la forma.

```
$consulta= '
    SELECT
        publicaciones.usuario AS user,
        amigos.id_1 AS id_1,
        amigos.id_2 AS id_2,
        publicaciones.id AS id
    FROM
        publicaciones pub
    JOIN 
        amigos am ON pub.usuario = am.id_1 
    WHERE 
        amigos.id_2 = ? '; // este signo '?' se llenará de forma segura más adelante.

$stmt = $dbConnection->prepare($consulta);
$stmt->bind_param('s', $id); // Aquí le pasas el id de forma segura con bind_param para que enlace el valor del $id de forma segura con la primer coincidencia del caracter '?'. 's' es de *string*

$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
```

Con `bind_param` es una forma de asegurarte que no tratarán de hacer inyección sql en tu código.

Para ver más información sobre prevención de ataques de inyección sql.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Para ver más sobre bind_param.

http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php